# Is it possible to generate and send a pdf file via email without saving the pdf file locally or on a server

Tags: php, email, pdf

I am generating a pdf file using fpdf, the file contains headings and the corresponding user input from a form which is collected using the post method. I am wanting to attach this pdf to an email so it can be sent to the user. I am going to use phpMailer to do this. I am wondering is it possible to give the pdf a name so it can be attached to the email, but the pdf is not saved on the server or on the users local computer.

the code below loops through the headers array and the form data. then it writes it to a pdf. I have attracted a static pdf file to the attachment parameter, this was just to test if the pdf file sends via email.

code

```
<?php 
require('fpdf.php');
require_once('mail/class.phpmailer.php');
?>
<?php


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {


$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();


$headers = ['first name', 'last name'];

$i = 0;

foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
if($k == 'submit') continue;


$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->write(40,$headers[$i++]);
$pdf->ln(10);
$pdf->write(40,"$v");
$pdf->ln(10);
$content = $pdf->Output('doc.pdf','F');
}
//$bodytext ='jdjdjdjdjd';
//$email = new PHPMailer();
//$email->From      = 'example@hotmail.co.uk';
//$email->FromName  = 'example';
//$email->Subject   = 'PDF AddAttachment';
//$email->Body      = $bodytext;
//$email->AddAddress( 'destination@hotmail.co.uk' );

//$file_to_attach = 'file/my.pdf';

//$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'my.pdf' );

//return $email->Send();

//$pdf->Output();

}
?>
```

Comment: Create a temporary file, send email, then delete the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FPDF has a output function, which can generate the encoded String.
See http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm

And PHPMailer can add Attachments from Strings.

So its

```
$content = $pdf->Output('S');
$email->addStringAttachment($content, 'my.pdf');
```

That simple.

Comment: I am getting an error saying that the document is closed

Comment: Yeah, had some trouble witn this before. Sometimes it is not able to do multiple outputs. Try only issue the Output command once. And then not write to it anymore.

Comment: Oh wait, this was TCPDF... But I guess this there the case too?

Comment: I was getting the error because the output lines was in my for loop

Answer (score -1):

yes there is a perfect source code you can download http://codexhelp.blogspot.in/2017/04/php-email-create-pdf-and-send-with.html

```
    /**/
    $mailto = $_POST['mailto'];
    $mailfrom = $_POST['mailfrom'];
    $mailsubject = $_POST['mailsubject'];
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];


    $description = wordwrap($description, 100, "<br />");
    /* break description content every after 100 character. */


    $content = '';

    $content .= '
<style>
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
}

table{
width:800px;
margin:0 auto;
}

td{
border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
padding: 10px; 
max-width:520px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}


</style>

';
    /* you css */



    $content .= '<table>';

    $content .= '<tr><td>Mail To</td> <td>' . $mailto . '</td> </tr>';
    $content .= '<tr><td>Mail From</td>   <td>' . $mailfrom . '</td> </tr>';
    $content .= '<tr><td>Mail Subject</td>   <td>' . $mailsubject . '</td> </tr>';
    $content .= '<tr><td>Firstname</td>   <td>' . $firstname . '</td> </tr>';
    $content .= '<tr><td>Lastname</td>   <td>' . $lastname . '</td> </tr>';
    $content .= '<tr><td>Description</td>   <td>' . $description . '</td> </tr>';

    $content .= '</table>';


    require_once('html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');


    $to = $mailto;
    $from = $mailfrom;
    $subject = $mailsubject;  

    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr');

    $html2pdf->setDefaultFont('Arial');
    $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));

    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr');
    $html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);


    $message = "<p>Please see the attachment.</p>";
    $separator = md5(time());
    $eol = PHP_EOL;
    $filename = "pdf-document.pdf";
    $pdfdoc = $html2pdf->Output('', 'S');
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));




    $headers = "From: " . $from . $eol;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol . $eol;

    $body = '';

    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
    $body .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol; //had one more .$eol


    $body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol . $eol;
    $body .= $message . $eol;


    $body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename . "\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol . $eol;
    $body .= $attachment . $eol;
    $body .= "--" . $separator . "--";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {

        $msgsuccess = 'Mail Send Successfully';
    } else {

        $msgerror = 'Main not send';
    }
```